# gRPC: why is there no CompleteAsync() on a server-to-client stream?

Tags: streaming, grpc

After uploading data from a client to a server using a RequestStream, you have to call CompleteAsync() on the RequestStream to indicate you're done. However, if you are downloading data from a server to a client using a ResponseStream, there doesn't exist a CompleteAsync() on that stream. Why is that so?